# Manage UAG Server via WinRM

Tags: winrm, powershell-v3.0, microsoft-forefront-2010

Does anyone know of there is a way to configure a UAG server to work with WinRM? We have a small number of servers and the "Server Manager" application as well as PowerShell are the way we generally keep an eye on our systems. This is not connected to the public Internet and is used strictly as a reverse proxy for certain locations.

I have added the admin clients to the `Remote Management Computers` group on the UAG server and I have created a Firewall Policy allowing ports 5985 and 5986. It's not clear to me what else I might need to do here. And, of course, WinRM is installed and configured.